# Compiler error when browsing a deployed asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

```
CS0016 compiler error when browsing a deployed asp.net website IIS 7.5 WIN7
```

I met this problem when trying to browse my website. I searched a lot on the Internet, but I could not make it even when I gave full control to everyone in the security tab of several temp folders. Any ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by using cmd to uninstall and install asp.net in IIS7.5. Hope this will help others.